# Is the center of the universe at absolute rest?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, reference-frames, universe

A twelve year old relative of mine asked me: If after there is a center of the universe (maybe the center is the point where the bigbang happened), could it be at absolute rest? Because everything is moving around the center! So in this universe, the center is at absolute rest. But Newton said there should be nothing that is at absolute rest.

I am also confused. What can I reply?

Answer (score 2):

In our current models of the Universe, there is no "center". The Big Bang didn't happen "at a place", the best description is it happened "everywhere".

Comment: I heard big bang occurred from a singularity, which in other word can be considered as a point. And universe is expanding since. Actually I have no idea how this explosion looks like?

Comment: Perhaps reading the wiki on it might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang 
It's beyond the scope of a comment for me to explain the details of a "big bang" or what a "singularity" is. Suffice to say, it is not "a point" in space-time.

Comment: @dipu To add a bit to enumaris's comment, the current model of the universe includes space *itself* expanding.  When you start considering things like that, you find that a lot of things which were intuitive in simpler scenarios become surprisingly nuanced.

Comment: After reading some portions of Wikipedia article some of my misconceptions have been cleared. I misunderstood the Hubble's law all along! It does not say universe is expanding, but the space itself is increasing somehow 

Comment: the universe does not make sense at all

Comment: @dipu, the only things in the universe which are required to make sense are physics graduate students...